# Where does popcorn-time store downloaded movies

Tags: disk-usage

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I can't find folder where Popcorn-Time stores movies I've watched.
I would like to free some space that is occupied by this app. 
I have checked advanced settings -> Cache Directory (/tmp/Butter) and it's empty. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't delete them after you've watched them? That would probably be a smart decision for a streaming program, I could see gigs and gigs of space being filled up fast. Anyway, try `baobab` / Disk Usage Analyzer (run as root) to see what's taking up all your disk space, it could be something else. (ps. I thought Popcorn time wasn't going to work anymore, it's still ok? Like it?)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, I found it to be under

```
/tmp/Butter
```

Popcorn time deletes the files when you close it. In advanced settings you can enable the setting(Clear Tmp folder after closing app?) if you have accidentally disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code:

```
Settings.tmpLocation = path.join(os.tmpDir(), Settings.projectName);
```

So on Linux it would be:

`/tmp/Popcorn-Time/TorrentCache/`

Note that it gets deleted when you close the application.

Comment: Yes, it's true.That folder ir really empty. But, I'd like to free space which is occupied after watching movie.

Answer (score 0):

On version `popcorntime-0.4.4` stores files in `/tmp/Popcorn-Time`